# Winsock using send() and FD_WRITE

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, send

I'm new to Winsock. I am writing an HTTP server and I am aiming to send a large file by reading and sending in chunks. To optimize this process, I attempt to use a nonblocking socket where I read the next chunk from the disk while I send the current one.

My problem now is that I get an FD_WRITE message even when it seems the buffer should be full and my function deletes the associated data from memory prematurely. I believe this causes my responses contain less data than they should send() stops sending prematurely and the client (which is a well-known one) receives about 70% of the data. When I use blocking sockets it works fine, it's just longer.

I tried using Wget, a simple HTTP client, to get a better idea of what's going on. From what I can see, the datastream thins out when I detect WSAEWOULDBLOCK errors when checking for errors after using send(). It looks like during those sends, not all the data gets sent.

When I set the sleep time to over 2000ms after checking for the FD_WRITE message, everything works as it basically comes down to using a blocking socket. I also tried setting times around 100-200ms, but those fail as well. As it is, the condition checking for FD_WRITE always returns valid before entering the loop.

```
WSAEVENT event = WSACreateEvent();
const int sendBufferSize = 1024 * 64;
int connectionSpeed = 5; //estimated, in MBytes/s
const int sleepTime = sendBufferSize / (connectionSpeed * 1024 * 1024);
size = 0;
const int bufSize = 1024 * 1024 * 35;
int lowerByteIndex = 0;
int upperByteIndex = bufSize;
size = bufSize;
int totalSIZE = 0;
unsigned char* p;
unsigned char* pt;
clock_t t = std::clock();

p = getFileBytesC(resolveLocalPath(path), size, lowerByteIndex, upperByteIndex);
lowerByteIndex += bufSize;
upperByteIndex += bufSize;
totalSIZE += size;
while (upperByteIndex <= fileSize + bufSize)
{
    int ret = send(socket, (char*)p, size, 0);
    pt = getFileBytesC(resolveLocalPath(path), size, lowerByteIndex, upperByteIndex);
    totalSIZE += size;
    lowerByteIndex += bufSize;
    upperByteIndex += bufSize;
    if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
    {
        while (SOCKET_ERROR == WSAEventSelect(socket, event, FD_WRITE))
        {
            Sleep(50);
        }
    }
    Sleep(sleepTime); //should be around 30-50ms. Wait for the buffer to be empty
    delete[] p;
    p = pt;
    std::cout << std::endl << (std::clock() - t) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
send(socket, (char*)p, size, 0);
delete[] p;
std::cout << std::endl << (std::clock() - t) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
if (totalSIZE == fileSize) std::cout << std::endl << "finished transfer. UBI=" << upperByteIndex;
else
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "ERROR: finished transfer\r\nBytes read=" << totalSIZE;
}
Sleep(2000);
closeSocket(socket);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't write correct non-blocking `send()` code without storing the value returned in a variable. It is the number of bytes actually sent. You can't assume the entire buffer was sent in non-blocking mode.
2. If `send()` returns -1 with `WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK` or whatever it is, *then* is the time to call `WSASelect(),` or `WSAEVENTSelect()` if you must, but with a timeout. Otherwise, i.e. if it returns a positive count, you should just advance your offset and decrement your length by the amount sent and repeat until there is nothing left to send.
3. Your sleeps are just literally a waste of time.

But I would question the whole approach. Sending on a blocking-mode socket is asynchronous anyway. There is little to be gained by your present approach. Just read the file in chunks and send the chunks in blocking mode.

Comment: Ok, I assume you mean `WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK`. So I now check for the return value and only enter the loop if it is -1 and the error is `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`. I am getting the same results however. I updated the code. As to your last comment, I don't understand, the approach is made so that I can perform operations in the same thread while sending data, how else should I go about it to achieve the same thing?

Comment: @Æðelstan He meant that sending data with a *blocking* socket won't wait until the data got transmitted etc., just until the data is copied somewhere in your RAM => You won't gain anything using nonblocking sockets on the sender site to read from the HDD in the meantime because the sending time is negligible. ... Receiving data with blocking/nonblocking can have notable time differences, but not sending. The only time a blocking send really blocks [a long time].is when the kernel buffer is full and can't get processed correctly; in this case there is something wrong with the connection anyways

Comment: @Æðelstan And in that same case your non-blocking code has to wait as well.

Comment: EJP and @deviantfan Ok, thanks for clearing this up about blocking sockets. But do you think the kernel buffer issue is the problem with this code then, or what is it? The data buffers are 35MB.

Comment: @Æðelstan The issue is that you do this:`int ret = send(socket, (char*)p, size, 0);` . After this send() call, you **MUST**  account for the fact that `ret` may be less than `size` . e.g. you ask it to send 1000 bytes, but perhaps send() sent only 721 bytes. (Also, remove your Sleep calls, there is nothing right about having them there.)

Comment: @nos Ok, but why would it not send all the bytes given in the parameters then? I cannot understand...

Comment: 1. Because that's what the return value is for, and 2. ***Because you're in non-blocking mode.*** That's what happens in non-blocking mode when there isn't enough room in the socket send buffer for all the data. That's what *has* to happen. It can't block, and it would be asinine to give you an error when maybe all but one byte could be transferred.

Comment: Ok, but the socket send buffer in this case is set to 64KB and the data chunks are 35MB, and most of them _do_ get sent intact even though the buffer is much smaller than the data chunk to be sent. So what do you mean when you say "when there isn't enough room in the socket send buffer for all the data"?

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you don't understand about that. In any case all you have to do is use blocking mode and get rid of the selects and sleeps and the whole issue will disappear.

Comment: What I don't understand is why most chunks are sent whole while some are not, considering that the buffer is always 64KB big.

Comment: Because of TCP, the receiver's receiving speed, the intervening network, other loading or network use on your host, ... You don't have any reason to expect perfection. If it behaved perfectly why would it need to return a count?

Comment: Ah, right, I'm getting too tired... Of course it makes sense! So non-blocking means it will stop sending if there are too many transmission issues instead of waiting to resolve them, right?

Comment: Non-blocking mode is non-blocking mode. If it could wait it wouldn't be non-blocking, would it?

Comment: Taking that as a yes, +1 for your time and your explanations! Thank you your patience.

Comment: It's a yes that is also trying to get you to think.

Comment: @Æðelstan You are using TCP. TCP will segment the data into whatever makes sense at the time, which is a complex combination of how the network behaves, how fast/slow the other end is and so on. Just because there is a buffer of 64kb doesn't mean that there's always room for 0 or 64kb of data. TCP might decide to send about 1460 bytes to fill an up ethernet frame, or it might decide to send 155 bytes since that's all the receiver have room for at the moment. Then you get a write event that there's available data in the socket buffer, which might just be a few bytes.

Comment: @Æðelstan I don't know what you mean by that. But if you push 64kb down to the socket, and TCP managed to send 16kb of that before you return WSAEventSelect(). you will get a write event, since there's now 16kb available in the buffer out of 64kb. (And by the time you get to the send() call, perhaps TCP has sent out even more data)

Comment: @nos Right, but if you push down 1MB it will take until all the data has been sent or until there less than 64KB of data left in the buffer and TCP stops sending for FD_WRITE to be sent right?

Comment: @nos nevermind, from the documentation FD_WRITE is sent only after WSAEWOULDBLOCK actually.

Comment: @Æðelstan It will take until there is *some* space in the socket send buffer for `FD_WRITE` to be notified. Exactly how much space is indeterminate, but it certainly doesn't wait until the buffer has been completely emptied. That would be a waste of time.

Comment: Ok, that seems to match my experience. So `FD_WRITE` is notified regardless of the state of the socket, such as there having been a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error or no error at all? The documentation says about `FD_WRITE`: "...when a socket is accepted with accept [...] and then after a send fails with WSAEWOULDBLOCK and buffer space becomes available."

Comment: That doesn't contradict what I just said. You asked whether it waits until the buffer is empty, and I answered that.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't trying to though. But how can there only be SOME buffer space left if a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` is returned? Wouldn't the buffer be cleared on such an error, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Æðelstan If WSAEWOULDBLOCK is returned, there is no more space. But a nanosecond later, TCP might have sent out some data, and then more space becomes available. The socket buffer isn't cleared. The data remains in the socket buffer until TCP sends it out(and it gets ACK'ed), or you close the socket. If there is 16kb available in the socket buffer, and you try to send 1MB data, your send() call will fill in 16kb of your data in the socket buffer, send() will return 16kb, and it's up to you to manage sending the remaining (1MB-16kb) of data.

Comment: @nos ok thanks, now I understand how `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` and TCP work together. However, in my code, my send() calls send out 35MB with a single call even with a 64KB buffer, without it being up to me what I do with 35MB-16KB, so what about that?

Comment: @nos Then I also don't understand in my code why I get WSAEWOULDBLOCK and then FD_WRITE when there is still data queued up to be sent! Is there not a whole 64KB of the queued up data present in the buffer when WSAEWOULDBLOCK is sent???

Comment: @Æðelstan You're getting it *because* there is still data queued up to be sent. In the socket send buffer. It is full. So the write can't do anything. So it signals `EWOULDBLOCK`. You get `FD_WRITE` when the socket send buffer transitions from being full to having some space for another write.

Comment: Yes I understand I get the `EWOULDBLOCK` when it is full. But in my code I am getting the FD_WRITE before all data is transmitted and that's the part I don't get and the main point of my question!

Comment: Sigh. You get it when there is space in the socket send buffer for another write. I've stated that several times now. I've also stated that it doesn't wait until the buffer is empty, and I've also stated why.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but why would there be space for another write if not all data has been sent??

Comment: I mean why would you want to write?

Comment: @Æðelstan Sigh again. If TCP manages to send one byte and receive acknowledgment for it, there is now one byte of free space in the buffer. You would want to write because now you can. Why would you want to wait until the buffer is empty? This is your theory: you justify it.

Comment: I see... So basically I just can't use `FD_WRITE` the way I thought I could. I understand everything we talked about at last... Thank you both a ton!

Comment: Because if I write at that point it seems to overwrite the data waiting to be transferred to the buffer from my tests. And this is why my whole function failed to transmit all the data.

Comment: @Æðelstan No. Your whole function failed for reasons which have already been enumerated at length, and specifically because of your failure to do anything with the value returned by `send().` You've been told that at least four times. This conversation is just going round in circles. The latest piece of clarification was first provided over an hour ago, and the information about `send()` was first provided four hours ago in my answer above.

Comment: If you think so, however I did do somthing about the return value a LONG time ago...

Comment: @Æðelstan Perhaps you didn't do it correctly ? It's very hard to discuss code we can't see.

Comment: @Æðelstan I do think so, and that conclusion is soundly based on the available evidence. 'Did do something about the return value' conveys nothing. I am commenting on the code you have posted here. I don't know what else you can rationally expect.

Comment: ok, what exactly can I do about the return value other than see that not all bytes were sent? If not all bytes are sent what can I possibly do but wait for them to be sent?

Comment: besides, right now I am getting either the full data length or `SOCKET_ERROR` with `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` as return values, which don't help a whole lot, other than knowing some chunks could not be transmitted _yet_.

Comment: and EJP as far as `FD_WRITE` is concerned take a look at this answer (which I had read before posting here) http://stackoverflow.com/a/12208948/2402806
This is what my code was attempting to take advantage of if by "remaining data" he means in my case remainiing chunks.

Comment: and as far as the first comment goes, it is wrong; I have read from reliable sources that blocking sockets block until the data is _sent_ not until it is _copied to memory_

Comment: @Æðelstan I don't see anything in the answer you cited that disagrees with anything I have said here. And your so-called 'reliable sources' are just dead flat wrong. It blocks until the data is transferred to the socket send buffer. Not to the network. The suggestion is ridiculous. If it was the case, none of this return value/SD_WRITE/select business would be necessary. It also contradicts your other assertions here. You aren't making much sense.

Answer (score 2):

The `TransmitFile` function exists to solve exactly this problem for you. It does the whole thing entirely in kernel mode so it's always going to beat a hand-crafted version.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740565(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit: On Linux there's the somewhat similar `sendfile` call.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile

(The ubiquity of web servers helped to motivate OS designers to solve this problem.)

Comment: Wow, I did not know about this. I will be sure to give this a try, although I also want something that can be tweaked for Linux eventually.

Comment: I tried `TransmitFile`, but I got maybe marginally better results than with my original function using blocking sockets. That is 200Mbps vs ~185Mbps on localhost. Here is my code
`HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(resolveLocalPath(path).c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
TransmitFile(socket, hFile, fileSize, 1024 * 1024 * 35, NULL, NULL, TF_USE_KERNEL_APC | TF_WRITE_BEHIND);
CloseHandle(hFile);`
Is there any way to make it faster? I've tried several combinations of buffer size and TransmitFile block size (big and small).

Comment: I've always just set the block size to 0 (use default). Local host seems like a fairly bogus test (there are definitely faster ways to do IPC). In any case, how fast do you need it to go, and what is the limiting factor?

Comment: Well I tested it on LAN yesterday. The result was it made my network adapter crash and I had to restart both the adapter and my home router. Any idea why?!